# Imagemagick composite blur results in black area

Tags: imagemagick

I am composing an image from two input images - one with text and one background image.
When using the `composite -blur` option I get black areas to the right and to the bottom of the overlaying text. Example here:

[image]

This is my imagemagick command:

```
composite -blur 400 -geometry +16+193 example.png background.jpg result.png
```

I have tried the `repage` and `trim` commands to avoid the black areas but that did not work.

Does anyone have a good tip for me?

Comment: Which imagemagick version are you using?

Comment: @Andrea ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2012-08-17